# craps probability question

Tags: statistics

The following exercise is best solved with a computer.
The probability of winning a game of craps (a dice-throwing game played in casinos) is 244/495.

a.  What is the probability of winning 5 or more times in 10 games? Please give the answer to four decimal places.

I had trouble figuring this one out. I tried variations of things including (244/495)(10)/5.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $n$ games and the probability of winning a game is $p$ then the probability of winning exactly $k$ games is: $$\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$
Here $q:=1-p$.

You are dealing with a binomial distribution having parameters $n$ and $p$.

The probability of winning $m$ or more games is: $$\sum_{k=m}^n \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$The calculation in four decimals is not the job of a mathematician. For that you can use a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You can win:

- strictly 5 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^5 \binom{10}{5}\left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^5$
- strictly 6 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^6 \binom{10}{6} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^4$
- strictly 7 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^7 \binom{10}{7} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^3$
- strictly 8 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^8 \binom{10}{8} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^2$
- strictly 9 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^9 \binom{10}{9} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^1$
- strictly 10 times $\Rightarrow p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^{10} \binom{10}{10} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^0$

So the  the probability of winning 5 or more times in 10 games is $$p = \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^5 \binom{10}{5}\left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^5 + \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^6 \binom{10}{6} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^4 + \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^7 \binom{10}{7} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^3+\left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^8 \binom{10}{8} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^2+\left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^9 \binom{10}{9} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^1+\left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^{10} \binom{10}{10} \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^0 = $$
$$= \sum_{i=5}^{10} \left(\frac{244}{495}\right)^i \cdot \binom{10}{i} \cdot \left(\frac{495-294}{495}\right)^{10-i} \approx 0.6046
$$ if my calculus was right ... hope so

Comment: You do not calculate 'strictly $k$' but (for instance) 'the first $k$'. This for $k=5,\dots,10$

Comment: You should therefore multiply the $k$th term by the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{10}{k}$.

Comment: sorry..forgotten, I'm correcting